# Meteor: using Sessions and ReactiveVar

Tags: meteor

When should you use `Session` and `ReactiveVar`? I use `Session` variable as a communication medium between components. Let's look at Stackoverflow for example.

[image]

I labeled three hypothetical components. Let's look at the `filters` component. If you click `Tags` then the `Main` components will show its questions based on your favorite tags. To do this, I will set `Session.set("Main/showTags", true)` when the `Tags` button is clicked. In the Main component, I will have a helper function like below:

```
Template.Main.helpers({
  posts: function() {
    var isTags = Session.get("Main/showTags");
    var isQuestions = Session.get("Main/showQuestions");
    ...
    if (isTags) {
      return Posts.find().sort({tags: 1}) // or something along the lines
    } else if (isQuestions) ...
  }
});
```

This has worked well in most cases but I've seen from a lot of places that I should refrain from using `Session` and use `ReactiveVar`. But If I use `ReactiveVar` everywhere, then I would need the reference to all template instances. I expect it to work well between direct parent and children templates (ex. inside the main component, there could be `VoteAnswerViewsButtonTemplate`) but how would you do it with `ReactiveVar` when you want independent components to talk to each other?

Here's my final question. How can I appropriately use `Session` and `ReactiveVar` to keep the scope of components and make them communicate with each other as well? Also, if I use `Session` the way I do now, am I polluting the global namespace unnecessarily?

Related Documents:

1. https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity
2. https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactivity-basics-meteors-magic-demystified/

Comment: `Session` can be destroyed from the client end. so that is not something you want to use for page navigation i assume.

Comment: I agree with @KawsarAhmed, I find it nicer to have a custom url, even when it's just for a filtered set, so I would probably use nested templates

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in features related to `Session` variables that differentiate them from a regular reactive dictionary global variable (like [@Kyll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31583007/3793161) stated) that you would declare, for instance, in your `client.js` file. The only difference is the `Session` "limitation" of being necessary accessible application wide.

I am very pleased to take advantage of this difference, when I use a [reactive dictionary](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict) or [reactive variables](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var) in a smaller scope. I consider I have three kind of scopes:

***1 - Global scope***. E.g. the current UI language, the UI skin. I use `Session` for that. Simple and global data, not the kind that could be confused with anything else.

***2 - A cluster of templates.*** Let's say, for example, that I create a page to generate and customize pdfs in my app. I will not reuse any of the components elsewhere. My cluster is a folder with three files, let's call them `pdfgenerator.html`, `pdfgenerator.js` and `pdfgenerator_controller.js`.

I use `pdfgenerator_controller.js` to extend the route with all the specifics.

In the `pdfgenerator.js` file, I have several templates that I all use in the cluster. At the beginning of the file, I create a reactive dictionary `pageSession` (similar to reactive variables) and I use it in all my cluster. It allows me to pass data among all my components.

***3 - Local scope.*** Whether it is a single template or a reusable component, it is meant to work alone. I won't use Session vars for those either. I do not want to overcrowd the `Session` name space. What I do is pass to my template every data I need to operate it during its instantiation.

It could be from Spacebars:

```
{{> mySingleTemplate data=myData}}
```

or using Javascript:

```
Blaze.renderWithData(Template.mySingleTemplate , myData, self.firstNode);
```

In the local scope case, I also use a `reactive dictionary` or `reactive vars` just to handle the reactivity happening within the single template. In this case, I try to avoid the situations where I need to reactively return data to the parent template. If *I have to* (i.e. I won't probably make a package out of it), I use a local *minimongo* collection declared as global in the scope of the parent template. This way, I can pass along informations from the reusable component to its parent.

*Example: an upload template. I use minimongo to store the name, size, type, status and url of each uploaded file. The minimongo collection is shared between the parent form template and the child uploader template.*

---

***Bottom line:*** I only use `Session` variables for basic and global information. If the data structure I need to share globally is too complex/large, I rely on a collection.

I am curious to know if I get it right, so this is as much an answer than a test to see if people agree with my way of doing things. All comments and advices are welcome.

Comment: for the third case, local scope, how do you allow child templates to access their parent templates' local reactive variables?

Comment: 4 possibilities: 1) it is not the third case, but the second: local reactive variables are shared by design | 2) If I need these data only during instantiation, I just pass them along my template call (see the answer) | 3) if I need to access them regularly I attach them to the parent template data context (`this.myVar = new Reactive-Var('foo');` where `this` is the parent template instance). I then access to them using `Template.parentData().myVar.get()`. I never had to do that, actually. | 4) the data is complex enough to make me rely on a minimongo local collection declared in the parent

Comment: I have one additional question. Referring to your original answer, do you declare the reactive variable inside if (Meteor.isClient) block outside of all templates so that all the templates can access it, right? Am I right if I say you don't try to attach it to a template instance? In other words, do you do this? http://pastebin.com/6LiLzjHq

Comment: Yes I do this. The only difference is that, since I use a file located in the `client/views` folder, I don't need to specify `Meteor.isClient`. Attaching it to a template instance seems to be an unneeded constraint if all my templates are in the same file. However, if they are not, it makes sense (see the case 3 above).

Answer (score 5):

Session vars get a bad rap. The truth is, they're just fine until your app gets big. You'll know when it's time to move away from Session vars when:

- You can't keep the var names straight (eg wtf does `isColumnHidden` mean again?) Or, the session vars form natural clusters (3 session vars for tooltips, 5 for tags, etc.).
- You want that Session info in the url so you can send someone a link & they see what you see

So, how do you resolve each problem?

- For the first example, create a package. For example, In one of my larger projects I create a `rightSideMenu` and `leftSideMenu` package. Each has their own ReactiveDict that I export to the global scope (eg `rightMenu.RD.get('col1Hidden')`). This keeps the approach modular. I can completely rewrite my menu code, but as long as I still expose the ReactiveDict, the API stays the same. *That said*, I still use a Session var to show/hide the left & right menus. Why? because Session is the perfect use for menus. I don't want a hidden menu to persist through browser sessions (ever close something you didn't know how to reopen?), but I do want it to persist through routes. In other words, I want it to last for that browsing *Session*.
- If you want the url to hold session info, you need to use params or query params. For example, if you've got a map with 100 markers & the user wants to send that page to his buddy with a specific marker selected, it makes sense that the url be something like `url.com/marker20`. But why stop there? You could also include the lat & lng of the map center: `url.com/marker/40.23432/122.2342`. Maybe that's too much, maybe not. You decide. In your example, this makes a LOT more sense than storing `isTag` in a session var because it lets folks bookmark it, use the back button, share it, and change it without using their mouse (yes, your userbase is as lazy as I am).

An additional note on your current setup is that you're using flags for something that is mutually exclusive, leading to a conditional hell. If you've got 2 vars that can't both be true, stop & rethink the design. So, if I HAD to use session vars, I'd do something like:

```
 currentTemplate = Session.get('filter') 
 {{Template.dynamic template=currentTemplate}}
```

In the end, you'll need to think about a lot more than just ReactiveVariables. What about dependencies? Not every module needs to access dependencies of every other module. Same goes for collections, methods, and even CSS. I say let it grow organically & when it hits you "hey, this is a component" then turn it into a package, export a variable, and keep it modular. Until that point, Session vars are fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is not polluting the global scope. Then why not make your own?

```
myComponentScope = {}; //Declare a global scope for this component
```

Then just place as many things as you want inside. For example,

```
myComponentScope.foo = new Reactive-Var('foo');
```

And if you want something that looks like `Session` you can add [Reactive-Dict](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict):

```
meteor add reactive-dict
```

And use it this way:

```
myComponentScope = new Reactive-Dict(/* Optional name */);
```

The optional name makes the dictionary persistent across hot-code pushes.
The API for this dictionary is the same as `Session`.

---

Thus, when you have something strictly local (one template), go for a `Reactive-Var`.
When it's something multiple templates of the same kind share, go for your own scope.
If it's something so important all your application will need it, use `Session`.

Comment: What would be the fundamental difference between that custom global scope and the Session? You can basically have a namespace convention within your session variables, like in his example: "Main/showTags", "Main/showQuestions"... So it would not really pollute it as long as you follow your defined namespaces?

Comment: Yes, BraveKenny asked the exact question I wanted to ask.

Comment: @BraveKenny Being able to create a new global namespace instead of setting `someData` in `Session` and realizing later, after five hours of debugging of a very inconsistent behaviour, that one of your colleagues also used `someData` for a completely different thing. "Namespace conventions" are a pain to impose to everyone and an easily avoidable source of bugs. Instead of storing everything at the same place, store it at multiple places.

Comment: @Kyll Thank you. One minor question though. If you declare it like that wouldn't it be accessible from all the templates? Is it any different from a `Session` variable? How can you make it accessible to the templates that are within current page (i.e. children of the current template)?

Comment: @MaximusS Yes, it would. On that it is no different than `Session`. You can even consider it as "another `Session`-like variable". I did not know you wanted inheritance of it over children of a template? If so, add it as a template variable and access it using `Template.parentData(n)`. Note that you can also restrict the scope of variables using a package approach.

Comment: it is not possible to access reactive variables via parentData